# Running a custom vim map keybinding once works but running it x number of times doesn't work

Tags: vim

I am trying to map the Ctrl-j key to join two lines using a comma. I have the following line in my .vimrc file

```
:map <C-j> A<space>,<ESC>J
```

This works fine when I press Ctrl-j once

```
Before           After
test             test , test
test             test
test
```

But when I try to join multiple lines at once by pressing "2Ctrl-j" I get the following

```
Before           After
test             test , , test
test             test
test
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I join multiple lines into one comma separated line? I tried replacing the `<Esc>` with a `<C-[>`, but that didn't work.

Also, is there a way to parameterise the joining symbol? For example, if I wanted to map Ctrl-k followed by any character to join two lines using the specified character, what would the map for that be?

Comment: Motions don't work like that. the 2 make you repeat A<space>,<ESC> twice, but J is executed only once. However, I'm not sure how to make this work with a motion.

Comment: `J` by default assumes a minimum of count 2. As in it joins the next 2 lines. If you passed typed 3 you would get three lines joined

Comment: @FDinoff Nope. Putting in 3 just gives me 3 commas. `test , , , test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is flawed because `2<C-j>`:

- tells Vim to append a comma 2 times to the current line (`2A<space>,`)
- and `J` won't take the count and thus only work once (even if it did, `J` is the same as `2J`…).

Also command sequences like `A<space>,<ESC>J` are better suited for macros. If you want your mappings to work with a count, you should use only one command (an Ex command is best) in the right hand side of your mapping and, if possible, a less "pedestrian" method.

Here is a better approach:

```
:nnoremap <C-j> :s/\n/ , <CR>
:xnoremap <C-j> :s/\n/ , <CR>
```

With these mappings, you can do `<C-j>` and `3<C-j>` in normal mode and `<C-j>` without problem. Here is what Vim does in the three scenarii above:

- normal mode `<C-j>` replaces the EOL with `,` on the current line

  ```
  :s/\n/ , <CR>
  ```
- normal mode `3<C-j>` replaces the EOL with `,` on this line and the two below

  ```
  :.,.+2s/\n/ , <CR>
  ```
- visual mode `<C-j>` replaces the EOL with `,` on each line in the visual selection

  ```
  :'<,'>s/\n/ , <CR>
  ```

As you can see, using an Ex command automatically inserts the right range and makes your mapping a lot more predictable.

***edit***

Basically, when you use a count before an Ex command or when you issue an Ex command in visual mode, Vim inserts automatically the range corresponding to that count or that visual selection *before* the command itself to save you some typing.

```
3<C-j>
```

does:

```
3:s/\n/ ,
```

which is transformed into:

```
:.             " from this line
:.,            " to
:.,.+2         " two lines below this line
:.,.+2s/\n/ ,  " do this substitution
```

Comment: Thank you. Just to clarify when you say "Ex command" you mean entering command by pressing ":" right? I am not sure I understand your second bullet point either. I would have thought it just ran the command 3 times in a loop, not sure where the `.,.+2` is being inserted in `:.,.+2s/\n/ , <CR>`. The solution works perfectly, I just ask for my own understanding.

Comment: Yes, "Ex commands" are the commands you enter at the `:` prompt. You can see what Vim does if you remove the `<CR>` at the end of the mapping, it's rather interesting. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using one of your registers you can store the command in a register.

For example you can add the following to your vimrc

```
let @j = "A,\eJ"
nnoremap <C-j> @j
```

The `@j` uses the `j` register to store the command. When you type a number followed by `@j` or `<C-j>` you will run the command n times which will join the next n lines seperated by commas.

---

Another way to join multiple lines together is to use the function below.

```
function! CustomJoinLines(delim) range
    for i in range(a:firstline, a:lastline) 
        exec "normal A" . a:delim . "\eJ"
    endfor
endfunction
```

This function will join multiple lines together using what ever delimiter you pass in. It will also keep the space that `J` normally adds.

To map this command add the function to your vimrc and the following nnoremaps

```
nnoremap <C-j> :call CustomJoinLines(" ,")<CR>
nnoremap <C-k> :call CustomJoinLines("!")<CR>
```

Comment: Both your suggestions worked excellently. Very hard to pick which answer to accept but Romainl's seems to be the simpler one.